# trying to use channels in Django caused these errors

Tags: python, django, wsgi, asgi

I was trying to use channels in Django, To do that I followed a tutorial and made these changes in the asgi.py file

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
{
    "http":get_asgi_application()
})
```

and these in the settings.py file

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'lostAndFound.wsgi.application'
```

after that, i restarted the server and got an internal server error, and the error in the terminal

```
`Exception inside application: WSGIHandler.__call__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alaa/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in **call**
return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
TypeError: WSGIHandler.**call**() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

can anyone plese help me with this

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in settings:

```py
# You have "wsgi"
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'
                                ^
                                |   
# And it should be "asgi"       v      
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.asgi.application'
```

Therefore the server does not work, because it expects to have asgi views provided (with different signature), and you feed wsgi in.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you import it : `from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application`

Comment: yeah it's imported in the asgi.py fille

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i mean i just didn't write it in the code that i have provided but it's in my project